# Dynamic image table in PHP from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a php page that reads a list of films from a database and displays the corresponding images in a table.

I've found quite a few examples of this, but havent successfully been able to implement it yet.

Has anyone got a link to a good tutorial on doing this or perhaps code you've used yourself?

so my images are stored in a folder 'images' on a server, and each entry in my table contains the colulmn 'imagelocation' which has a relative location, like "images/film1.jpg".

Ultimately the images will be clickable and will open a lightbox type view with the image and full info about the film.

any help appriciated!

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563512/use-php-and-mysql-to-add-images-to-a-gallery)?

Comment: Thanks for that, thats awesome!

Can anyone tell me how i add a connection string to this bit?

        <?php
        $images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
        while ($image=mysql_fetch_assoc($images))
        {